# What's the difference between a save and an epic save?

Tags: rocket-league

In Rocket League if a player saves a goal they are either awarded 50 points for a save or 60 points for an epic save. What's the difference between the two? From experience it seems that the ball is closer to the goal when an epic save occurs, but I'm wondering what the proper definition is.

Answer (score 3):

If the ball is on the goal line, partially in the goal, or very near the goal line, it will be called an epic save.

Comment: Any official sources confirming this?

Comment: @imulsion no, but thats the rule of thumb everyone knows

Answer (score 0):

An epic save is when it is about to go into the goal and you save it either as a part of the ball has crossed the goal line or when the ball is just about to cross the goal line. An ordinary save is when the ball has entered the goalie box marked on the floor.